# Painting a Front Catalytic Converter — Bad Idea or Not?

Tags: exhaust, paint, catalytic-converter

I need to replace the front catalytic converter on my 2006 Suzuki Aerio. The part came in bare metal, no paint or any coating is visible or possible to feel on the surface.

Should I not paint it to avoid messing with the heat dissipation properties? Or should I paint the part to prevent rusting? If so, what color — White or black?

[image: catalytic converter]

Comment: Many exhaust components are stainless ( 13 % Cr ) today and don't rust . About the only way to test at home is to put a drop of concentrated nitric acid on it - no reaction with stainless , dark spot for carbon steel . Caution ,nitric is very strong acid.

Comment: @blacksmith37 thank you! Even if it is potentially steel, I have reservations about painting it. I'm sure the temperatures are too high for the paint/enamel to not discolor/get destroyed. What are your thoughts on that?